# How to Discover pairing android devices over wifi

Tags: android, android-studio, adb, mdns

ADB supports pairing with code over wifi.
In Android Studio there is an automated discovery of devices that are in the pairing over wifi process.

Is there a CLI trick to perform this discovery process?
Meaning that I could pair devices over Wifi from CLI without Android Studio

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://android.stackexchange.com/a/247618/2241

Answer (score 0):

OK.
Adb has an MDNS utility.

To discover pairable devices in the network use the commend

adb mdns services

This will list the devices that are waiting for pairing and devices that are already paired and are available for connect.

For example:

adb mdns services

List of discovered mdns services

adb-RFAR9134C1M-lzUn3r  _adb-tls-connect._tcp.  192.168.0.176:44845

adb-RFAT83EQ2XE-KQ81RG  _adb-tls-pairing._tcp.  192.168.0.51:36719